# Algorithm for solving an ODE with time-dependent parameter numerically

Tags: ode, runge-kutta

Would anyone please explain me what is the mathematical algorithm to solve a IVP system of ODE with a time-dependent parameter. e.g.

```
   dy1/dt = a1(t) * y2 -b1(t)* y3 -c1(t) y1;
   dy2/dt = a2(t) * y1 -b2(t)* y1 -c2(t) y3;
   dy3/dt = a3(t) * y2 -b3(t)* y3 -c3(t) y1;
```

y(0)=c;
My idea so far is that for fixed time-step I should form a vector of a,b,c and assume a,b,c to be constant over that time-period. what about if the system is stiff?
Would anyone plaese give me an idea how to solve it using c++ boost library? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given an ODE $\dot{y}(t) = f(y(t), t)$, most -- if not all -- algorithms reduce to function evaluations and Jacobian evaluations at specified points in $t$ and $y$. To illustrate, a step of explicit Euler is

\begin{align}
y_{n + 1} = y_{n} + (t_{n + 1} - t_{n}) \cdot f(y_{n}, t_{n}).
\end{align}

If you have a time-dependent parameter, treat it as part of $f$, the function evaluation (respectively, for implicit methods, also treat it as part of the Jacobian evaluation). A similar strategy applies to more complicated methods for solving ODEs (multistage methods such as Runge-Kutta, implicit methods for stiff systems, etc.). This strategy is different than assuming your parameters are constant over a time step -- for a multistage method, assuming your parameters are constant over a time step will result in inaccurate function evaluations in intermediate stages and reduce the order of your method.

As for solving it using a C++ Boost library, you might try looking at the [Boost odeint](http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/) documentation.

Comment: Further to Geoff's answer, if you have a stiff system, and don't want to use a fully-implicit solver, you might want to consider these explicit solvers that are suited to stiff systems: http://dumkaland.org/

Comment: Thanks for contributing! This answer is better posed as a comment, since it does not address the original question. In addition, if you are the author of those solvers, you should state that, per site policy.

Comment: @ Geoff Oxberry Thank you a lot. if it is possible would you please tell me a reference or a web link discussing this topic in detail. I searched several books on numerical solution of ODE but nobody explicitly addressed this issue. I want to study this in more detail- specially stiff equations.                                                                                                                                                                                                  @user1533076  Thank you for your comment too. I will check that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ArijitHazra I doubt any book I recommend (texts like Hairer/Norsett/Wanner, Petzold, Butcher, Lambert) will explicitly address the issue either. Treating parameters as part of the function evaluation is a standard treatment for nonlinear ODEs. A specialized treatment for linear ODEs with variable coefficients could exist; I'm not aware of one. The comment about order reduction comes from my own experience writing and testing ODE solvers.